# In selenium how to pause a YouTube video embedded inside i frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I am trying to play a video & then pause it , the element is located inside a iframe I am able to play the video how can I pause the same , I am using button action to play but this is not available once video is playing

```
driver.get('https://demo.guru99.com/test/guru99home/')
frame1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/RbSlW8jZFe8']")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame1)

sleep(2)
Ytbutton = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button ytp-large-play-button-red-bg']")
Ytbutton.click() #play
sleep(2)
# for pause ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because upon pressing the play button, the button will be hidden afterward.

The easiest way without tinkering with hidden element would be simply utilizing `ActionChain` to invoke a space bar `send_keys(' ')` or k `send_keys('k')` command which is shortcut for Youtube player to pause and unpause a video.

Something like following :

```py
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver.get('https://demo.guru99.com/test/guru99home/')
frame1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/RbSlW8jZFe8']")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame1)

sleep(2)
Ytbutton = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button ytp-large-play-button-red-bg']")
Ytbutton.click() #play
sleep(2)
ActionChains(driver).send_keys('k').perform() #pause
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dig below in the iframe, you can find another changeable button:

```
pause_button = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ytp-play-button ytp-button']")
pause_button.click()
```

It, at the end of the video, turns into a "repeat". It is in the `<div class="ytp-left-controls">` block.